# newRow.insertCell of Javascript and JSTL

Tags: javascript, jstl

I want to add a combobox written in JSTL to a table, so i create this function:

```
function AddRow(){
        var newRow = document.getElementById('listuser').insertRow(-1);

        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);

        newCell.innerHTML = '<div class="styled-select"><form:select name="fonction" path="fonction"><c:forEach items="${fonc}" var="f"><form:option value="${f.code_fonction}">${f.ll_fonc}</form:option></c:forEach></form:select></div>';
```

But this works only if I use HTML code, without JSTL code.
How can I do it?

Comment: Why exactly do you think that JSTL runs in webbrowser? Webbrowser only understands HTML, CSS and JS. Java/JSP/JSTL runs in webserver and produces HTML/CSS/JS (as you can see by rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser). By the way, that's not a combobox, that's just an ordinary dropdownlist.

Comment: Ok i want to add a dropdowList on clicking on the button why it's not running? my project run in the server.

Comment: But JavaScript runs in the browser :) Just use HTML. Or, just use Java/JSP instead to produce that HTML based on a specific request (e.g. an ajax request?).

Comment: I resolve it :) Thanks. The function insertCell works also with JSTL.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It can however be used to **produce** the desired HTML/JavaScript code which ultimately runs in browser.